# objdump result not consistent? It shows different required libraries depending on how it's executed

Tags: android, c, libtool, objdump

It seems it's a not reliable behavior.

If I compile thrift c_glib library and show requirement of the libraries I found:
thrift/lib/c_glib$  objdump -p .libs/libthrift_c_glib.so | grep NEED

> **NEEDED               libgobject-2.0.so**
>
> **NEEDED               libglib-2.0.so**
>
> NEEDED               libintl.so
>
> NEEDED               libssl.so
>
> NEEDED               libcrypto.so
>
> NEEDED               libc.so
>
> NEEDED               libdl.so

Now, if I install and do the same command on installation directory and execute from the install directory. objdump -p x86/lib/libthrift_c_glib.so | grep NEED I get the same.

But If I go to the thrift source and execute the command to the installation patch... Surprise!!!

objdump -p /opt/android/x86_64/lib/libthrift_c_glib.so | grep NEED

> NEEDED               libssl.so
>
> NEEDED               libcrypto.so
>
> NEEDED               libc.so
>
> NEEDED               libdl.so

Some libraries dissapeared!!! Why?

Comment: Maybe your build and the prebuilt are built using different flags and settings?

Comment: You don't appear to be testing the same files, one is an x86 and the other is x86_64. Different builds might have different dependencies.

Comment: No, they are exactly the same files. I checked by sha256 sum. And the results are consistent. Even more I can recompile then, the result is exactly the same once and another. And I even copy to a git repository that does sha1 to compare and it says same files everytime.